# Adjacency matrix format networkx

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I use NetworkX on python to returns a graph from a numpy matrix as this :

```
adj = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((np.array(v), (np.array(i), np.array(j))), shape=(m, n))
Gp = nx.from_numpy_matrix(adj)
```

With :

```
print(np.shape(m), np.shape(n), np.shape(v), np.shape(i), np.shape(j) )
() () (3293952,) (3293952,) (3293952,)

print(m,n,v,i,j)
174338 174338 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.] [    0     0     0 ... 75841 74977 74975] [     1    859  85314 ... 173575 173575 173575]
```

It gives that kind of adjacency matrix (adj) :

```
(0, 1)  2.0
(0, 2)  1.0
(0, 859)  2.0
(0, 860)  2.0
(0, 861)  1.0
    ...
```

However, this is what I get

```
    --> 196     Gp = nx.from_numpy_matrix(adj)
    197 
    198 #     nx.number_connected_components(Gp)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/networkx/convert_matrix.py in from_numpy_matrix(A, parallel_edges, create_using)
    559     # coordinates will become the edges in the graph.
    560     edges = map(lambda e: (int(e[0]), int(e[1])),
--> 561                 zip(*(np.asarray(A).nonzero())))
    562     # handle numpy constructed data type
    563     if python_type is 'void':

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in __bool__(self)
    285             return self.nnz != 0
    286         else:
--> 287             raise ValueError("The truth value of an array with more than one "
    288                              "element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().")
    289     __nonzero__ = __bool__

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
```

I don't understand, as It worked few months ago and I literally touched nothing on this script or any dependancies.

**This exact adjency matrix format worked one month ago.**

Comment: You've share little bits of data and code here and there, but can you share an example that actually demonstrates the problem? For example by providing a sample `i`, `j`, `m`, `n` and `v`?

Comment: Just use `nx.from_scipy_sparse_matrix` instead of `nx.from_numpy_matrix`